# StorageHasher: Blake2 vs Twox

Tags: storage, hash, storagenmap

When creating a `StorageMap`, a hashing algorithm needs to be chosen for the `StorageHasher`.

`frame_support` provides [a few options](https://docs.rs/frame-support/2.0.0-rc2/frame_support/index.html#structs):

- `Identity`
- `Blake2_128`
- `Blake2_128Concat`
- `Blake2_256`
- `Twox64Concat`
- `Twox128`
- `Twox256`

(edit: the non-`*Concat` versions are being deprecated)

Where `Identity` means using the key directly (with no hashing), `Blake2_*` means using some variation of the [BLAKE2](https://www.blake2.net/) algorithm, and `Twox*` means using some variation of the [xxHash](https://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) algorithm.

The question here is: what criteria would one take into account when choosing BLAKE2 vs xxHash for their `StorageHasher` object? When to choose one over the other?

Comment: Commenting here as I'm not an expert...Blake2 is cryptographic and Twox is not. I'd say that's a matter of security x speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To complete the answers:

The deciding factor to choose *Blake2* (cryptographic hashing function) over *xxHash* (simple hashing function) is whether the input to be hashed is set by the users or by the system. In other words, the part of the storage key that can be "choosen" by users has to be randomly and uniformly distributed (aka secure) and for that we need a cryptographic hashing function. We need this property to avoid having unbalanced state tries in the chain storage.

For example, if *xxHash* was used as the `StorageHasher` for Account IDs, an attacker could create an unbalanced state trie, with a vanity account generator and some tokens to spare, just creating accounts with account IDs sharing the same trie prefix.

[This article by Shawn](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/) is a very good dive on the topic of storage keys.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation. Blake2 is a cryptographic hasher and it's slow while Twox is non-cryptographic and fast.